# Will future windows server OS support Asp Classic?

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server

Can anybody tell me, will future versions of Windows server operating system support ASP Classic (3). As my company product uses ASP classic in product and we support our product in all upcoming Windows server systems. But I heard from someone that Microsoft will not support ASP classic in 2 years.

Does anybody have information regarding this?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/lifecycle and http://support.microsoft.com/common/international.aspx?RDPATH=%2flifecycle%2fdefault.aspx%3fp1%3d12925

Comment: This would suggest that it will be around until 2022 at least. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669020/  But apart from that, there are still a lot of Classic ASP sites out there, and Microsoft would annoy a lot of customers were it to pull the plug

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will classic ASP pages run on versions of Windows past Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003837/will-classic-asp-pages-run-on-versions-of-windows-past-windows-7)

Comment: Yes, see the linked dupe.